# DADA2 truncLen value

Tags: statistics, analysis, dna-sequence, illumina

Hello i have done illumina sequencing and the median of my forward reads is 281 and reverse is 277 , i have plot barplot of reads length in attached pictures

I want to know how can i choose truncLen and what is the optimal truncLen values to use based on these reads lengths in forward and reverse files.

Thank you

[image]

[image]